# Did the 12 sons of Jacob marry outside the jewish race to start off their families?

Tags: history, marriage, avot-patriarch-fathers

Did the 12 sons of Jacob marry outside the Jewish race to start off their families?

Comment: related but without citation http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73312/the-rest-of-yaaqobs-daughters

Comment: You have a lot of characters to use in the post. There is no reason your question should ever only be one sentence and match the title.

Comment: Why would you think they did this?

Comment: Jewish race at this time was the family of Avraham as for Yitschak and Yaakov or somewhat other? Are you sure that there was a race?

Comment: ??? Jacob had only three sons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an argument in [בראשית רבה פ"ד כ"א](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%93_%D7%9B%D7%90) whether the brothers married Canaanite woman in the neighborhood or whether the brothers were also born with twin sisters and each one married a twin of a brother that wasn't also his brother from his mother.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think in my opinion the second argument is weak and rather concocted.  I have heard the later argument being told for Adam & Eve and it would make more sense for that situation.

Comment: רבי יהודה אומר לאחיותיהם נשאו השבטים doesn't translate exactly as presented here. And while it's true that there are  opinions who want to read the Medrash as meaning that, there are others who read it more directly.

Comment: Tamar certainly was a Canaanite.

Comment: @ClintEastwood how so?

Comment: @ClintEastwood According to the Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 85:10), she was from the line of Shem.

Comment: @user6591 I see Rashi, Ramban, Eitz Yosef and Matnas Kehuna all explain it that way.

Comment: Yup. It's the more common interpretation.

Comment: Right... I forgot that in this instance, "cannanite" is interpreted to mean merchant